# How to make Sync or Async HTTP Post/Get

Tags: android, http

I need Sync or Async HTTP Post/Get to get HTML data from Web-Service. I search this whole internet but I can't give good result.

I tried to use this examples:

- [Android Series get/post and multipost requests](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests/)
- [Jcabi.com](http://http.jcabi.com/)
- [Execute HTTP Post request in android](http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android)

but nothing of them working for me.

`HttpClient` and `HttpGet` is cross out, error is :

> "org.apache.http.client.HttpClient is deprecated "

Code:

```
try
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String getURL = "google.com";
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
    HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
    HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
    if (resEntityGet != null)
    {
        //do something with the response 
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: may be if you post what is the error in your try may lead to result.

Comment: I can't run app because  HttpClient and HttpGet is cross out, error is :
"org.apache.http.client.HttpClient is deprecated "

CODE:
try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String getURL = "http://www.google.com";
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
            HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
            if (resEntityGet != null) {

                //do something with the response

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: you need to find why you cant run

Comment: compilator get me this error: "org.apache.http.client.HttpClient is deprecated "

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/the-type-defaulthttpclient-is-deprecated/

Comment: it doesn't working for me

Comment: tell what you are getting instead of saying "it doesn't working for me –"

Comment: I can not understand you, what do you mean - "dot work "  :(:(

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated because they want you to use HttpUrlConnection. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The example I have posted below is based on an example that I found on the **Android Developer Docs**. You can find that example [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html), look at that for a more comprehensive example.

You will be able to make any http requests with the following

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new DownloadTask().execute("http://www.google.com/");
    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //do your request in here so that you don't interrupt the UI thread
            try {
                return downloadContent(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve data. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //Here you are done with the task
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private String downloadContent(String myurl) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        int length = 500;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(TAG, "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = convertInputStreamToString(is, length);
            return contentAsString;
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream stream, int length) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[length];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }
}
```

You can play around with the code to suit your needs

Comment: Compilator do not recognize: HttpURLConnection, URL, openConnection() and etc.

see image: http://postimg.org/image/sjaav97yx/

Comment: I added library but still is some errors,
see screen: http://postimg.org/image/re791wksx/

Comment: I'm missing this: private String downloadContent(String myurl) throws IOException  and at this moment errors disrepair :):) thank you for grate help, I'm testing my code and give you feedback.

Comment: Pleasure, remember to mark as the answer if it helped.

Comment: I have already mark your answer. Thank you A lot Neil :) you save my 3 days work

Comment: Can I put it in a file called Requester and use it from multiple activities? or it should be declared in every activity in tedious way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
which gives you everything you need. If you decide to use AsyncTask and program it yourself, I'd recommend to not have AsyncTask inside your Activity, but rather put it in a wrapper class and use a callback to that. This keeps your Activity clean and makes the network code reusable. Which is more or less what they did in Volley.

Comment: Volley is a great alternative, and actually a better option!

Answer (score 0):

```
**Async POST & GET request**

public class FetchFromServerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private FetchFromServerUser user;
    private int id;

    public FetchFromServerTask(FetchFromServerUser user, int id) {
        this.user = user;
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        user.onPreFetch();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        URL urlCould;
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            String url = params[0];
            urlCould = new URL(url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlCould.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();

            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        } catch (MalformedURLException MEx){

        } catch (IOException IOEx){
            Log.e("Utils", "HTTP failed to fetch data");
            return null;
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {

        //Do your own implementation
    }
}


****---------------------------------------------------------------***


You can use GET request inn any class like this:
new FetchFromServerTask(this, 0).execute(/*Your url*/);

****---------------------------------------------------------------***
```

For Post request just change the : connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); to

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");