# Android HTTP: Make more than 1 asynctask request

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio, sendasynchronousrequest

I followed this post to set up an Http Async Request: [HttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936865/how-make-sync-or-async-http-post-get-in-android-studio)

So, now, I call: `new DownloadTask().execute("http://www.google.com/");`
to make this request.

How can I manage different calls? For example:

```
new DownloadTask().execute("http://www.google.com/");
new DownloadTask().execute("http://www.facebook.com/");
new DownloadTask().execute("http://www.twitter.com/");
```

And have different results?

Comment: How do you want the calls to be made? One after the other?

Comment: No.. I need to make a call and when the first one is finished, make another. That's why sometimes I need the result of first to use as a param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass one more argument to the `AsyncTask`. Make some constants corresponding to your tasks.

```
new DownloadTask().execute("http://www.google.com/", DownloadTask.ID_ASYNC1);
new DownloadTask().execute("http://www.facebook.com/", DownloadTask.ID_ASYNC2);
new DownloadTask().execute("http://www.twitter.com/", DownloadTask.ID_ASYNC3);
```

Inside `AsyncTask`, use this id to identify which is the request being called.

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    //Variable for storing the req id
    private int id;

    //Constants corresponding to your tasks
    public static int ID_ASYNC1 = 0;
    static static int ID_ASYNC1 = 0;
    static static  int ID_ASYNC1 = 0;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        id = params[1]);
        //your code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(id == ID_ASYNC1){
            //Do your task #1
        } else if(id == ID_ASYNC2){
            //Do your task #2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible "OnPostExecute" to return to the MainActivity class the JSON result?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you need to create an `interface` for that. See this link, http://cyriltata.blogspot.in/2013/10/android-re-using-asynctask-class-across.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `looper` for smooth downloading for multiple file it will download them one by one. In this way your application run smoothly huge huge amount of downloads.

**How to use Looper**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DownloadThreadListener,
      OnClickListener {

   private DownloadThread downloadThread;
   private Handler handler;
   private ProgressBar progressBar;
   private TextView statusText;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // Create and launch the download thread
      downloadThread = new DownloadThread(this);
      downloadThread.start();

      // Create the Handler. It will implicitly bind to the Looper
      // that is internally created for this thread (since it is the UI
      // thread)
      handler = new Handler();

      progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
      statusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);

      Button scheduleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.schedule_button);
      scheduleButton.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();

      // request the thread to stop
      downloadThread.requestStop();
   }

   // note! this might be called from another thread
   @Override
   public void handleDownloadThreadUpdate() {
      // we want to modify the progress bar so we need to do it from the UI
      // thread
      // how can we make sure the code runs in the UI thread? use the handler!
      handler.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            int total = downloadThread.getTotalQueued();
            int completed = downloadThread.getTotalCompleted();

            progressBar.setMax(total);

            progressBar.setProgress(0); // need to do it due to a
                                 // ProgressBar bug
            progressBar.setProgress(completed);

            statusText.setText(String.format("Downloaded %d/%d", completed,
                  total));

            // vibrate for fun
            if (completed == total) {
               ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE))
                     .vibrate(100);
            }
         }
      });
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View source) {
      if (source.getId() == R.id.schedule_button) {
         int totalTasks = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;

         for (int i = 0; i < totalTasks; ++i) {
            downloadThread.enqueueDownload(new DownloadTask());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**DownloadThread.Class**

```
public final class DownloadThread extends Thread {

   private static final String TAG = DownloadThread.class.getSimpleName();
   private Handler handler;
   private int totalQueued;
   private int totalCompleted;
   private DownloadThreadListener listener;
   public DownloadThread(DownloadThreadListener listener) {
      this.listener = listener;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      try {
         // preparing a looper on current thread
         // the current thread is being detected implicitly
         Looper.prepare();

         Log.i(TAG, "DownloadThread entering the loop");

         // now, the handler will automatically bind to the
         // Looper that is attached to the current thread
         // You don't need to specify the Looper explicitly
         handler = new Handler();

         // After the following line the thread will start
         // running the message loop and will not normally
         // exit the loop unless a problem happens or you
         // quit() the looper (see below)
         Looper.loop();

         Log.i(TAG, "DownloadThread exiting gracefully");
      } catch (Throwable t) {
         Log.e(TAG, "DownloadThread halted due to an error", t);
      }
   }

   // This method is allowed to be called from any thread
   public synchronized void requestStop() {
      // using the handler, post a Runnable that will quit()
      // the Looper attached to our DownloadThread
      // obviously, all previously queued tasks will be executed
      // before the loop gets the quit Runnable
      handler.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            // This is guaranteed to run on the DownloadThread
            // so we can use myLooper() to get its looper
            Log.i(TAG, "DownloadThread loop quitting by request");

            Looper.myLooper().quit();
         }
      });
   }

   public synchronized void enqueueDownload(final DownloadTask task) {
      // Wrap DownloadTask into another Runnable to track the statistics
      handler.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            try {
               task.run();
            } finally {
               // register task completion
               synchronized (DownloadThread.this) {
                  totalCompleted++;
               }
               // tell the listener something has happened
               signalUpdate();
            }
         }
      });

      totalQueued++;
      // tell the listeners the queue is now longer
      signalUpdate();
   }

   public synchronized int getTotalQueued() {
      return totalQueued;
   }

   public synchronized int getTotalCompleted() {
      return totalCompleted;
   }

   // Please note! This method will normally be called from the download
   // thread.
   // Thus, it is up for the listener to deal with that (in case it is a UI
   // component,
   // it has to execute the signal handling code in the UI thread using Handler
   // - see
   // DownloadQueueActivity for example).
   private void signalUpdate() {
      if (listener != null) {
         listener.handleDownloadThreadUpdate();
      }
   }
}
```

**DownloadTask.Class**

```
public class DownloadTask implements Runnable {
   private static final String TAG = DownloadTask.class.getSimpleName();
   private static final Random random = new Random();
   private int lengthSec;
   public DownloadTask() {
      lengthSec = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      try {
         Thread.sleep(lengthSec * 1000);
         // it's a good idea to always catch Throwable
         // in isolated "codelets" like Runnable or Thread
         // otherwise the exception might be sunk by some
         // agent that actually runs your Runnable - you
         // never know what it might be.
      } catch (Throwable t) {
         Log.e(TAG, "Error in DownloadTask", t);
      }
   }
}
```

**DownloadThreadListener.class** (**interface**)

```
public interface DownloadThreadListener {
   void handleDownloadThreadUpdate();
}
```

Using this you can add huge amount of downloads it will add them queue.
[**Complete tutorial**](http://androidsrc.net/android-loopers-and-handlers-code-tutorial/)

Comment: Right now I need to construct my url string. I use an PHP file that it is on the server.. How do I do?

Comment: how you are hitting url?

Comment: Hitting? What do you mean?

Comment: means how are you trying to reach your server?

Comment: Ehm, using the AsyncTask?